# readableStream is locked while using .json()

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch, fetch

everyone!
I got a problem: I'm trying to validate registration form. Totally, it works ok, but I need to validate form via server. In my case, for example, I need to figure out if email is already taken.

I tried to fetch and async/await syntax, but problem is still the same:
`DOMException: "The operation was aborted. "`
The way I understand it right now is `readableStream` (what actual response body is) is `locked`. So the wrong error is thrown, and I cannot get server response.

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(options.url, options.requestOptions);
    const body = await response.json();
    if (options.modifyDataCallback instanceof Function) {
      body.data = options.modifyDataCallback(body.data);
    }
    return body.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
```

How do I see the solution? I send request and recieve some server error like

```
code: email_in_use
message: Email '...' is already in use.
```

Then I need to throw error and catch it in other place in order to show corresponding error message to client.

In browsers network tab I do receive what I want to receive, but can't get the same JSON-response in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google chrome provided more information: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200.
And the problem was on backend. It is written in C# and API method returned `Task`. The problem was solved by adding async/await for this method.